# Logical operator with different types

Tags: javascript, loops, logical-operators, console.log

I'm trying to solve the famous *FizzBuzz* quiz but I decided to use the logical operator **or** instead of **else** to provide fullback.

```js
for (var num = 1; num <= 100; num++) {
  var output;
 if (num % 5 === 0 && num % 3 === 0) {
     output = "FizzBuzz";
    } else if (num % 5 === 0) {
     output = "Buzz";
    } else if (num % 3 === 0) {
     output = "Fizz";
    } 
  console.log(output || num);
}
```

This was supposed to print all the numbers from 1 to 100, with some exceptions. For numbers divisible by 3, print "Fizz" instead of the number, and for numbers divisible by 5, print "Buzz" instead and "FizzBuzz", for numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5.

But it doesn't print any numbers.

Comment: Your `console.log(output || num)` outputs `output` is it is defined. If it is not defined, it outputs `num`. Because `output` is defined, it gets outputted, and `num` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will say that Zakaria's answer is correct, but for exposure's sake, here is my answer

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var output = "";
  if (!(i % 3)) output += "Fizz";
  if (!(i % 5)) output += "Buzz";
  console.log(output || i);

}
```

My logic here:
set the output value to be equal to `""`, which evaluates to a falsey value.

If a number *is* divisible by 3, then `i % 3` will be 0, this is also a falsey value so we flip it by using the `!` operator. Assume that `i=9`, then `! (i%3)` = `!(9%3)` = `!(0)` = `!(false)` = `true`.

Therefore, if `!(i%3)` becomes true we append our empty string with "Fizz", then we use the same sort of logic for `i%5`, but instead appending "Buzz"

*Note* the order of these two if statements is important -- flip them around and you'll get BuzzFizz instead of FizzBuzz.

If output is *not* the empty string we set it to originally, `output || i` will return the value of `output`, giving us "Fizz", "Buzz", or "FizzBuzz" depending.

If ouput *is* empty, then `output || i` will return the value for `i`

Answer (score 3):

The `output` declaration could be `num` like :

```
var output = num;
```

So you don"t have to use the `||` operator and just print the `output` directly :

```
console.log(output);
```

```js
for (var num = 1; num <= 100; num++) {
  var output = num;
 if (num % 5 === 0 && num % 3 === 0) {
     output = "FizzBuzz";
    } else if (num % 5 === 0) {
     output = "Buzz";
    } else if (num % 3 === 0) {
     output = "Fizz";
    } 
  console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: they could also just make output's default value an empty string as `"" || 'yes' ` will return `yes`

Comment: But I thought that when I don't define a value to a variable it takes undefined automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to fix the `output`'s scope:

```js
for (var num = 1; num <= 100; num++) {
  let output;
  if (num % 5 === 0 && num % 3 === 0) {
    output = "FizzBuzz";
  } else if (num % 5 === 0) {
    output = "Buzz";
  } else if (num % 3 === 0) {
    output = "Fizz";
  } 
  console.log(output || num);
}
```

---

Also, the `||` could be removed if you initialize `output` with `num`:

```js
for (var num = 1; num <= 100; num++) {
  let output = num;
  if (num % 5 === 0 && num % 3 === 0) {
    output = "FizzBuzz";
  } else if (num % 5 === 0) {
    output = "Buzz";
  } else if (num % 3 === 0) {
    output = "Fizz";
  } 
  console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between let and var. Why let works and var doesn't